# To change data adapter from jdbc to jpa

Tags: java, jpa, report

I used connection from jdbc tu fill my report in jasperreport.
Now I have changed tecnology to connect to my db and I use jpa with Hibernate.

When I try to connect to my db from Jaspersoft Studio, I get this exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.ejbql.EjbqlDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(EjbqlDataAdapterService.java:95)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.reader.DatasetReader.start(DatasetReader.java:190)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.property.dataset.dialog.DataPreviewTable$4.run(DataPreviewTable.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.ejbql.EjbqlDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(EjbqlDataAdapterService.java:79)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2021)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:895)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:728)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3625)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3579)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1381)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
    ... 8 more
```

In my classpath there is this list of library:

[image]

Now I use the JRBeanCollectionDataSource class to pass a collection of bean to my report:

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista);  
jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(JASPER_REPORT_FOLDER + "java.jasper", parameters, beanCollectionDataSource);
```

but, What should I use instead of JRBeanCollectionDataSource? (Obviously, if your application will work)

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: NoSuchMethodError ... you have a persistence-api.jar for JPA 1.0 and a JPA implementation for a more recent version of JPA (or vice versa). This would be found by searching on the internet in many other places

Comment: Yes I have readed this in internet but I can not understand...

Comment: so its down to what is in the CLASSPATH ... you have some Hibernate jars, but maybe tomcat has some others perhaps, and what version of JPA does that version of Hibernate need?

Comment: The first comment would be: Yes I have readed this on the internet but I can not understand ... Excuse me I have hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.jar ... Is not It for jpa 2.0 ?? ??

Comment: I have not other jar of hibernate... Just that you see

Comment: JPA API can be defined in other jars, typically called "persistence-api.jar". The fact remains, at runtime there is some JAR in the CLASSPATH that has the annotation OneToMany present in it and it DOESN'T HAVE the method orphanRemoval(). Only you can see that CLASSPATH and you have many tools at your disposal to view it